# como envio comandos ZPL desde node js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Saludos cordiales a todos:
Veran estoy tratando imprimir una etiqueta con lenguaje de zebra,desde node js
hasta ahora ya se pudo conectar con la impresora de zebra (S4M) e imprimir.
El problema que tengo es que solo imprime texto plano y no interpreta el código de zebra.
Alguien sabrá si existe una librería o algo parecido que me permita enviar los códigos de zebra a una impresora desde node js? o una manera de poder realizarlo.
Cualquier ayuda o comentario se los agradeceré mucho.
Este es el fuente que se lleva hasta el momento.
Muchas gracias :)

```html
     require('node-native-printer/src/windows_printer.js'.setPrinter);

require('./lib.js').your_function();
const printer = require('node-native-printer');
constWindows =require('node-native-printer/src/windows_printer.js')
const lista=printer.listPrinters(constWindows);


console.log(lista);
let printer_name= 'ZDesigner S4M';
printer.setPrinter(printer_name)

function printZebra(filename, options,  printer_name){
    // printer.setPrinter(printer_name)
    // console.log('________________________________________________');
    // printer.printerInfo(printer_name)
    // printer.print(filename,options, printer_name)
    var text = '^XA^LH15,15^FO15,10^BY2^BCN,55,N,N,N^FD[[CODIGO]]^FS^FO100,72^A0,30,23^FD[[CODIGO]]^FS^FO285,15^A0,60,53^FD[[PRECIO]]^FS^FO25,100^A0,24,20^FD[[PRODUCTO]]^FS^XZ'
    printer.printText(text,options, printer_name)//imprime txt

}

printZebra("C:\impresion_zebra.txt", {
    "collate": true,
    "color": true,
    "copies": 1,
    "duplex": "Default",
    "landscape": false,
    "paperSize": "",
}, printer_name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No conozco hasta el momento ninguna librería en NodeJS que permita realizar esto, sin embargo implementé una solución en LabView que podría ser aplicada en esta ocasión. Los pasos serían los siguientes:

1. Generar un archivo de texto plano (txt) con el texto a imprimir (usando los respectivos códigos de Zebra).
2. Imprimir éste por medio de la shell de windows. Comparta la impresora por red y mediante el comando `NET USE LPT1:<ruta> /PERSISTENT:YES` (verifique el puerto de la impresora) envíe la impresión del archivo. Así realicé las primeras pruebas manuales exitosas.
3. Mediante la librería de node `node-cmd` realice los mismos pasos, no envíe directamente la impresión desde NodeJS.

Comment: gracias Johann .. me sirvió tu respuesta :)

Comment: @Johann `NET USE LPT1:<ruta> /PERSISTENT:YES` en ruta te refieres a la ruta del archivo ?